# Creating new output from 2 CSVs in Python (data manipulation)

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file called cities formatted like so:

```
City_id,City,Population,Weather,State
la01,LA,24,72,CA
ny01,NY,12,42,NY
bo01,BO,32,65,BO
```

and another csv called shipping:

```
Carrier,Type,Path,Packages,Max_Packages
UPS,Truck,la01-ny01,100,200
UPS,Truck,la01-bo01,100,200
UPS,Air,la01-ny01,100,500
UPS,Air,bo01-ny01,100,500
```

I need to write these to a string where each row starts with the city and has a list of all its destinations (the list should be sorted by type):

```
la01:LA [Truck="ny01:100,200 + bo01:100,200" Air="ny01:100,500"];
bo01:BO [Air="ny01:100,500"];
```

I attempted to break this up by first reading the cities csv into a dictionary, then grabbing each key (city_id) and storing it in a list for later use. I'd use the city id to match against the shipping csv and had a loop going through looking for all paths starting with whatever city id I was currently iterating on. From there I had if statements to check the Carrier and was going to split the values up into either the Truck or Air dictionary. This solution however is getting very convoluted and doesn't handle the fact that there can be multiple occurences of the same exact Path string. Any simpler way to do this?

Comment: Can you share the current solution?

Comment: Are the strings you've shared as the desired result exactly what you need, or a representation of what you think it might look like, but not exactly the text output you require?

Comment: From your description @asdf, I think you were on the right track. It's good to post the code you attempted along with the question so that we can give you tips and pointers rather than just throw solutions at you...  as I just did =) I think you'll find it useful.

Comment: @Todd I responded to your post with a comment, not too sure if it notified you since I wasn't able to @ you, sorry for spam if it's a double notifiy

Comment: @asdf - I accidentally deleted a parenthesis when transferring the code to this page. I fixed it - it should work if you update the file paths to your csv files.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of reading in the CSV and putting the data into a format that fits the needed report output. For that, a dictionary makes it easy to group the routes by the city - using the city as the dictionary key.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import partial
from operator import itemgetter

city_data = (r for r in csv.DictReader(open('city_data.csv', 'r')))
path_data = (r for r in csv.DictReader(open('path_data.csv', 'r')))

# Seems we only need city_data for id<=>city mapping. Simple dict works.
city_codes = {d['City_id']: d['City'] for d in city_data}

dest_data = defaultdict(partial(defaultdict, list))

package_data = itemgetter('Path', 'Type', 'Packages', 'Max_Packages')

for rec in path_data:
    path, type, packages, max = package_data(rec)
    city_id = path[:4]
    city    = city_codes[city_id]
    dest_data[f'{city_id}:{city}'][type].append(f"{path[5:]}:{packages},{max}")
```

`dest_data` then contains:

```
defaultdict(..., 
    {
        'la01:LA': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, 
            {
                'Truck': ['ny01:100,200', 'bo01:100,200'], 
                'Air':   ['ny01:100,500']
            }), 
        'bo01:BO': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, 
            {
                'Air':   ['ny01:100,500']
            })
      })
```

Now you've got the data organized like you want, it's just a matter of adjusting the data for display like you have in your example.

```
>>> for city, pkg_routes in dest_data.items():
...     pkg_info = (f'{type}="' + ' + '.join(pkg_list) + '"' 
...                 for type, pkg_list in pkg_routes.items())
...     print(f'{city} [' + ' '.join(pkg_info) + '];')
...     
la01:LA [Truck="ny01:100,200 + bo01:100,200" Air="ny01:100,500"];
bo01:BO [Air="ny01:100,500"];
```

The path data can be iterated over and the dictionary updated by two keys - which translates into a group and subgroup: by city, and by route type.

Using a `defaultdict` that gives us an empty list to add route information to whenever a new key is added is very convenient.

An idiomatic way to construct a multilevel `defaultdict` is to pass a `partial` object as the parameter to its constructor. The `partial` can be set up to create a sub-`defaultdict` that generates new lists on demand. In the example, the 2-level dict will give us an empty list to append route info to when a new key is added.

`itemgetter` is another convenience tool which can grab several keys from the `path_data` dictionary at once and return a tuple of values.

One last small note on good practice. It's good to use a generator when specifying a comprehension (parenthesis vs. square brackets), as this reduces the number of loops in algorithms. Thus, the `path_data` CSV file accesses are combined with the loop that produces the final dictionary.

Comment: thanks for the info! When copying and pasting the first block of code it doesn't even run however. The three "from" import statements are greyed out and unused. I'm getting "Unresolved reference 'd' " for city_codes={d...., and a whole bunch of other errors on basically every line. Here's what I'm seeing: https://ibb.co/RvH7N3V

Comment: There were a couple parenthesis missing when I transferred the code to this page. It would have showed up in the stack trace as `SyntaxError` if you tried to run it. I fixed the code. You should be able to cut-n-paste it as is. Except you need to update the names of the files because they're likely different on your system.